# Qt title bar кастомизация

Tags: python, c++, qt, pyqt

Можно ли как-то сделать такую границу у крестика стандартным (`stylesheet`, например) способом? 
Или писать свой обработчик нужно, который сам всё будет рисовать и т.д...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: надо писать например: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/855760 , https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1178951 , https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1251644 , https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1058817 , https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1168409 , https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/851868 , ...

Comment: @S.Nick, спасибо, почитаю)